# Custom anntotation to wrap annotations

Tags: java, annotations, jax-rs

In a JAX-RS endpoint, I can be repeating lots of methods with:

```
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = HTTP_STATUS_CODE_200_MESSAGE),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403),
        @ApiResponse(code = 409),
        @ApiResponse(code = 429),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500),
        @ApiResponse(code = 501),
        @ApiResponse(code = 503),
        @ApiResponse(code = 509) })
```

Is it possible to wrap all these annotations into one new custom annotation?

Comment: Reviewing https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X#apiresponses-apiresponse and http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.0/apidocs/index.html?io/swagger/annotations/ApiResponse.html I'm not seeing any way to share or re-use ApiResponse values.

Comment: What would be nice would be a way to tag ApiReponse instances with a reference ID on one method, and to use those responses by reference on other methods.